# Why doesn't a line appear on my Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to draw a simple line in Tkinter using a `Canvas`. I have this code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
rt = Tk()
rt.geometry('500x500')
head = Canvas(rt, width=500, height=100)
head.create_line(1, 99, 499, 99)
rt.mainloop()
```

When I run the program I only get a plain white screen. Why doesn't the line appear?

Comment: You never actually added the Canvas to your window - typically by either the `.pack()` or `.grid()` methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the question to ask it clearly and explicitly according to the site standards - please carefully study the changes, to be able to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As @jasonharper mentioned, you aren't actually adding the canvas widget to the UI with a geometry manager like `pack()`, `place()` or `grid()`. Try...

```
import tkinter as tk  # avoid star imports if you can!
from tkinter import ttk
rt = tk.Tk()
rt.geometry('500x500')

head = tk.Canvas(rt, width=500, height=100)
head.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)  # <- add this
head.create_line(1, 99, 499, 99)

rt.mainloop()
```